# Java polymorphism confusion

Tags: java, types, polymorphism

The question below is from Java SCJP5 book by Kathy Sierra and Bert Bates.
Given a method declared as:

```
public static <E extends Number> List<E> process(List<E> nums)
```

A programmer wants to use the method like this:

```
// INSERT DECLARATIONS HERE
output = process(input);
```

Which pair of declarations could be placed at // INSERT DECLARATIONS HERE to allow the code to compile? (Choose all that apply.)

A.

```
ArrayList<Integer> input = null;
ArrayList<Integer> output = null;
```

B.

```
ArrayList<Integer> input = null;
List<Integer> output = null;
```

C.

```
ArrayList<Integer> input = null;
List<Number> output = null;
```

D.

```
List<Number> input = null;
ArrayList<Integer> output = null;
```

E.

```
List<Number> input = null;
List<Number> output = null;
```

F.

```
List<Integer> input = null;
List<Integer> output = null;
```

G. None of the above.

Correct Answers given are: B, E, F and the explanation in the book states:
"The return type is definitely declared as List, NOT ArrayList so A,D are wrong. ......"

This is what I don't get...why it is that the return type MUST be List only and not ArrayList?? Just like the argument can be ArrayList then why cant return type also be arrayList?

Thanks

Comment: Thanks everyone, its much clearer now. I am taking away the fact that the return type needs to be the interface(List in this case) itself as the method can return any type of class which implements the List interface such as ArrayList, Linked List...etc.

Comment: only valid if using List and ArrayList from the java.util package...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is actually not specific to generics, but deals with types.

Easy way to think of it is, an `ArrayList` is a `List`, but an `List` is not necessarily an `ArrayList`.

`ArrayList` implements the `List` interface, so it can be treated as a `List`. However, just because something implements `List`, it is not an `ArrayList`. For example, `LinkedList` implements `List`, but is not an `ArrayList`.

For example the following are allowed:

```
List arrayList = new ArrayList();
List linkedList = new LinkedList();
```

This is because both `ArrayList` and `LinkedList` both implement the `List` interface, so they both can be handled as `List`s.

However, the following is not allowed:

```
ArrayList arrayList = new LinkedList();
```

Although both `ArrayList` and `LinkedList` implement `List`, they are not the same class. They may have similarities by implementing the methods of `List`, but they are completely separate classes.

Comment: Not strictly true - this is akin to the old "square is a rectangle, but a rectangle's not a square" argument. A List *can be* an ArrayList, but it is not *guaranteed* to be an ArrayList. There's a small but important difference.

Answer (score 13):

Because ArrayList is a subclass of List, so the List returned by process is not guaranteed to be an ArrayList.  For example, it could be a LinkedList instead.

Answer (score 3):

When you specify a return of type List, you're saying that the return can be **any** kind of List, whether it be an ArrayList, LinkedList, or other kind of List. If you try to return an ArrayList, you're being too specific - it's no longer a generic List.

Comment: basically what I felt like saying. Am not quite sure whether I formulated my thoughts correctly (clearly enough)

Comment: We said effectively the same thing. You make a good point about process not being able to choose the concrete implementation of List - I like that phrasing.

Answer (score 3):

The return type **could** be an ArrayList, but it could also not be an ArrayList, it could be a LinkedList, or some Collections List wrapper or other things. In order to assign it to a variable either you have to use the highest level type it could be (List in this case) or downcast if you know it **must** be an ArrayList.

In practice, variables should almost always be typed as List (if not Collection). There is almost never a good reason to actually reference the concrete type for these classes.

The only reason I can think of is if you have a method that will require random access to a List and you want to ensure you are not getting a LinkedList for performance reasons and the List is too large to reasonably copy to an ArrayList for the purpose of random access.

Answer (score 1):

The `process` method will not be in a position to decide which concrete implementation of List to choose. Its signature gives you a promise that it will be able to operate on ANY List (ArrayList, LinkedList, etc...) and can only specify that the return value will be SOME List.

For example, if the returned object is a LinkedList you couldn't assign it directly to a variable declared as ArrayList, but you could treat it as a List. Therefore A. and D. are not correct. You can't have your variable declared as ArrayList.

Answer (score 1):

You can declare return type to be `ArrayList`, but it would require an explicit cast, like so:

```
ArrayList output = null;
output = (ArrayList)process(input);
```

...which is contrary to what generics allow you to accomplish.

Comment: and you would have to rely on the actual object returned to be `castable` to ArrayList (An ArrayList or a derivate of it)

Comment: That's right-- you would get a runtime exception if you mistakenly cast to the wrong type of object, whereas generics will tell you at compile time whether the variable assignment is valid or not.  Plus I believe this would result in an annoying warning in your IDE about the unchecked cast.

Answer (score 0):

It is because the question explicitly says the method returns List<T>. You may very well change the method definition to return ArrayList<T>, but that's a different question. A List<T> can be many different types of list.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to look at this is "assignment compatibility". Semantically, the method call

```
output = process(input)
```

is equivalent to

```
nums = input;
/* body of process... */
output = returnVal; /* where process exits with "return returnVal" */
```

We know that `nums` has type `List<E>`, so the type of `input` must be "assignable" to `List<E>`. Likewise, we know that `returnVal` (i.e, the return value of `process`) type `List<E>`, so `List<E>` must be "assignable" to the type of `output`.

In general, a type `T` is "assignable" to a type `U` if `T` is a subtype of `U` (including the case where `T` and `U` are the same).

Hence, the type of `input` must be `List<E>` or a subtype of `List<E>` (e.g., `ArrayList<E>` or `LinkedList<E>`). Similarly, the type of `output` must be `List<E>` or a *supertype* of `List<E>` (e.g., `Collection<E>` or even `Object`).