# Generics confusion

Tags: java, generics, collections, polymorphism

Below is a question from Kathy & Bert Bates SCJP 5 preparation CD. I have posted this elsewhere too, but have not gotten a satisfactory explanation until now.... Please help me understand this:

```
public class BackLister {  
  //Insert code here
  {
    List<T> output=new LinkedList<T>();  
    for(T t:input)  
      output.add(0,t); 
    return output;  
  }  
}
```

Which of the following can be inserted at `//Insert code here`?

- **A**. `public static <T> List<T> backwards(List<T> input)`
- **B**. `public static <T> List<T> backwards(List<? extends T> input)`
- **C**. `public static <T> List<T> backwards(List<? super T> input)`
- **D**. `public static <T> List<? extends T> backwards(List<T> input)`
- **E**. `public static <T> List<? super T> backwards(List<T> input)`
- **F**. `public static <? extends T> List<T> backwards(List<T> input)`

I understand that A and B are correct; however, not why are D and E also right. I can see that C and F are also incorrect. Can someone please tell me why D and E are correct.

Comment: As far as I can see, all answers are the same. Am I missing something?

Comment: Looks like SO does not properly escape less-than (or ampersand) characters. I assume missing pieces are generic declarations.

Comment: you posted this question elseqhere? NO there's an EXACT DUPLICATE by YOU, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/858656/java-polymorphism-confusion

Comment: @MasterPeter: Same book, different question.

Comment: Yes, its a different question MasterPeter!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer D, `public static <T> List <? extends T> backwards(List <T> input)`, returns a list that can contain type `T` or any of its subclasses. Since it can hold `T`, it can hold any element in the input, and is "correct" in that sense.

Answer E, `public static <T> List <? super T> backwards(List <T> input)`, is similar, but returns a list that can hold `T` or any super class. Since it can also hold the input elements, it is also "correct."

Choosing one of these alternatives will impact what a user might expect to do with the resulting list.

- With the `List<? extends T>` output, one can iterate over the list and assign each element to a variable of type `T`, but no elements, even of type `T`, can be safely added to the `List`. (Someone might be referring to this list as `List<SubT>`, and would get a `ClassCastException` when trying to retrieve the `T` as a `SubT`.)
- With the `List<? super T>` output, one can safely add elements to the `List` if they are of type `T`. However, an element from the list can only be safely assigned to a variable of type `Object`. (Someone might be referring to this list as `List<Object>`, and adding instances of `Object` or other superclasses of `T`).
- With the `List<T>`, one can safely assign the elements of the list to a variable of type `T`, and can add elements of type `T` to the list (assuming it's a modifiable `List` implementation).

Comment: What, then, is the use of the type List<? super T>, since you can only extract the elements as Objects?

Comment: Items of type T can be added to a List<? super T>. The "owner" of the list might refer to it as List<SuperT>; it can iterate over the elements and access them as SuperT, while it exposes the list as a List<? super T> to other, who can add elements to the list.

Answer (score 1):

Because a `List<T>` is a `List<? extends T>` and a `List<? super T>`, by definition.
`? extends T` is a wildcard indicating `T` or a subtype, and `? super T` is a wildcard indicating `T` or a supertype. Therefore, returning a `List<T>` will satisfy both return types.

There are reasons for preferring to return one or the other, but the main point here is that they are legal.